# Position sticky in <table> does not work in Firefox and Chrome 58

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

1. Go to http://charliepark.org/css-only-sticky-headers/
2. Scroll down until "The First 40 Elements" table is visible.
3. Keep scrolling down till the end of page.

In Chrome 57 the table header will stick, but not for Chrome 58. Turns out it is not sticking in Firefox as well.

I am not sure whether both browsers are wrong now, or it was Chrome that was wrong but correct now. Either way, what is the proper way to make table header sticky?

Comment: Is sticky positioning even defined for internal table boxes? I highly doubt it, considering *none* of the existing positioning schemes are defined either.

Comment: They says ***"This only works (for now) on the latest versions of a WebKit-based browser, like Chrome Canary or the WebKit Nightly build. (I’m on Chrome 23.0.1263.1). More browsers will hopefully support this before too long."***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like said [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=975644#c30), Chrome still supports position sticky in table cells.
So a possible workaround is to point CSS to `th` instead of `thead`.
Please, see this sample: https://jsfiddle.net/owfmwdpm/

Comment: Does that still work for you? The example provided doesn't work for me neither in Firefox 49 nor in Chromium 52.

Comment: Does not work in FF. As of Feb 2017 `position: sticky;` for `th` doesn't work in FF `58.0 (64-bit)`

Answer (score -1):

So to answer your question:

> what is the proper way to make table header sticky?

The best way is to use a combination of jquery/javascript and css.

The jQuery adds/removes a class from the element that you want to make sticky, based on it's position on the page and in the viewport as the user scrolls. The css updates it's position property accordingly, applying a position value of `relative` when it is not sticky and `fixed` when it is sticky.

That article you referred to has a link with examples:
https://github.com/kingkool68/stickyHeader

Comment: @Green Question was asked last year and the guy was having problems with older browser versions & cross browser support. https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky